# Como carregar as dependências javascript no próprio javascript

Tags: javascript

Tenho um arquivo javascript que necessita de outros para funcionar corretamente

é um trampo gigantesco ficar sempre lembrando de chamar quando for usar esse js em algum lugar (até porque só de pensar nisso me trouxe até aqui)

Existe uma forma de carregar esses js dentro do js pai?

Comment: Estás a usar compilador?  podes dar um exemplo de que tipo de scripts são? têm dependências na npm ou ficheiros locais? esses ficheiros estão online ou no disco?

Comment: não possuem nenhum tipo de dependencia npm,  e não estou usando compilador (estou estudando vue mas ainda não peguei a manha).
Estão locais

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Importar um arquivo contendo tags script e link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/207237/importar-um-arquivo-contendo-tags-script-e-link)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este problema é resolvido utilizando o conceito de import e export.

Import e Export são palavras-chave do JavaScript usadas para implementar o conceito de módulos ES6. Eles permitem que você divida seu código em partes menores e reutilizáveis, chamadas módulos, e compartilhe funções, objetos ou valores entre esses módulos sem a necessidade de ficar importando também as dependências.

export: É usado para exportar funções, objetos ou valores de um módulo, tornando-os disponíveis para serem importados por outros módulos. Você pode ter várias exportações em um único módulo.

```
//Exemplo de exportação:
// module.js
export function minhaFuncao() {
  // ...
}

export const minhaVariavel= 42;
```

import: É utiizado para importar funções, objetos ou valores exportados por outros módulos para o módulo atual.

Exemplo:

```
// main.js
import { minhaFuncao, minhaVariavel} from './module.js';

myFunction();
console.log(minhaVariavel);
```

E dentro do arquivo html você pode importar um módulo usando a tag comum de importação adicionando o atributo type="module", por exemplo:

```
<script type="module" src="meu-modulo-javascript.js"></script>
```

E dentro deste módulo você pode fazer import de outros módulos como explicado anteriormente.

Esta é a solução mais moderna atualmente, mas outras soluções foram criadas como o require. Você pode encontrar mais detalhes sobre o require em : https://requirejs.org/ e mais detalhes sobre como usar módulos ES6 (import e export) em [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) e [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: Nem lembrava mais dessa pergunta que fiz há 6 anos atrás kkkkkk. Obrigado pela excelente resposta, tenho certeza que sua resposta irá ajudar outros!

Comment: De nada Pedro :-), se achou a resposta útil não esquece de votar. Abraços!

Comment: seria legal incrementar na resposta como importar os módulos no browser através da tag script pra ficar bem completinho a resposta.

Comment: Boa sugestão, feito!